# What changed in the way to implement a block?

Tags: blocks, 8

The documentation for Drupal 8 lists the following hooks as the ones necessary to implement a block.

- [`hook_block_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_access/8) controls which users have access to a block
- [`hook_block_view_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_alter/8) is used to alter how a block implemented by other modules is rendered
- [`hook_block_view_BASE_BLOCK_ID_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_BASE_BLOCK_ID_alter/8) is a specialization of the previous hook, similarly to what [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/8) is for [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8)

What I don't find is [`hook_block_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7), which in Drupal 7 allowed to expose the blocks defined from modules, and [`hook_block_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7), which was invoked when a block defined from a module was rendered in a page.

How do modules expose blocks, in Drupal 8? How are the blocks rendered?

Comment: This question is part of a series of questions whose purpose is highlighting the differences between Drupal 7 and Drupal 8.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the "Powered by Drupal" block as an example:

### Drupal 7

#### modules/system/system.module

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function system_block_info() {
  $blocks['powered-by'] = array(
    'info' => t('Powered by Drupal'),
    'weight' => '10',
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
  );
  return $blocks;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */
function system_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'powered-by':
      $block['subject'] = NULL;
      $block['content'] = theme('system_powered_by');
      return $block;
  }
}
```

### Drupal 8

#### core/modules/system/src/Plugin/Block/SystemPoweredByBlock.php

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\system\Plugin\Block\SystemPoweredByBlock.
 */

namespace Drupal\system\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Component\Annotation\Plugin;
use Drupal\Core\Annotation\Translation;

/**
 * Provides a 'Powered by Drupal' block.
 *
 * @Plugin(
 *   id = "system_powered_by_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Powered by Drupal"),
 *   module = "system"
 * )
 */
class SystemPoweredByBlock extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    return array(
      '#children' => theme('system_powered_by'),
    );
  }
}
```

The `hook_block_info()` is replaced by an [annotation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-common/en/latest/reference/annotations.html), containing all of the necessary metadata within the `@Plugin` portion of the docblock. `hook_block_view()` is replaced by the `BlockPluginInterface::build()` method.

The directory structure is the key here. All blocks must be placed into a specific directory within their module folder (src/Plugin/Block).